# Aplicar animation a div con background image

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo el siguiente código

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}

#loader {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QRgZIhI.png) no-repeat center 0;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Quiero que se aplique el efecto `animation: pulse` a la imagen, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Intenté con `@keyframes`

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite } 

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite } 

@-o-keyframes pulse {
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite } 

@keyframes pulse {
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite }
```

Pero tampoco me funcionó.

En un principio hice un gif animado en un sitio web que daba ese servicio, pero la calidad es muy deficiente, por eso opté por esta medida.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La regla `@keyframes` (o puntos de trayectoria) permite controlar los pasos intermedios en una secuencia de animación CSS.

Puedes usar la propiedad `transform` con el valor `scale` para dar el efecto que buscas.

Si deseas que la animación vaya más rápida o más lenta, cambia el valor de los segundos en `animation` a un número menor o un número mayor, respectivamente.

```css
#preloader {
   position: fixed;
   top:0; left:0;
   right:0; bottom:0;
   background: #fff;
   z-index: 100;
   
 }
 #loader {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   left:50%; top:50%;
   background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QRgZIhI.png) no-repeat center 0;
     margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:     pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
 }
  
   @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
     0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);}
     50% {-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);}
     100% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);}
 }
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="loader"></div>
  </div>
```

---

PD: `pulse` no es un valor predefinido en la propiedad `animation`.